# Prevent API Gateway from receiving requests for a robots.txt file

Tags: amazon-web-services, robots.txt, aws-api-gateway

I've been working on a new project that leverages an API Gateway mapped to a lambda function.  The lambda function contains a Kestrel .NET web server that receives requests via proxy through API Gateway. I have remapped API Gateway to an actual subdomain to ensure some branding consistency. Everything is working fine; however, I recently implemented Elmah.IO in order to get a better understanding of what errors are coming up in this unusual context.

Now, about one to five times per day, the api gateway URL is getting a request for a robots.txt file that it is unable to complete.  I wouldn't expect the API to be able to complete this request because the API is not meant to serve static content.  My question is; how can I prevent these requests from being made?

What is causing the API Gateway URL to be requested? Is it because it is directly detected through the links from my host site?  It's using CORS to access the API, so it's possible the robot could be detecting the API as a completely separate domain and attempting to crawl it.  If so, is there some configuration I could add to my Web API to force a text response of my design for the robots.txt request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching my way around for a little bit, I eventually just tried to dynamically generate my text file for robots.txt response.  I was reading the article over at: http://rehansaeed.com/dynamically-generating-robots-txt-using-asp-net-mvc/

This gave me the idea to dynamically generate the request.  As such, I set up the following:

```
[Route("/")]
public class ServerController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("robots.txt")]
    public ContentResult GetRobotsFile()
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder.AppendLine("user-agent: *");
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("disallow: *");

        return this.Content(stringBuilder.ToString(), "text/plain", Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you should rather use `disallow: /` (https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Answer (score 16):

### What is causing the API Gateway URL to be requested?

Web crawlers look for any URLs they can find and want to index everything. If there's a reference to your API gateway URL anywhere out there, odds are Googlebot and its friends will find it. They don't have any reason to know in advance that a domain is there for programmatic access only, from their perspective API URLs are just URLs like any other.

Well-behaved web crawlers will request the robots.txt file for a domain before requesting anything else, to see if they should load any other pages on the domain.

### How can I prevent these requests from being made?

I hate to tell people that they're asking the wrong question, but really you *want* crawlers to request it. That's how you can tell crawlers the other pages that you *don't* want them to request. The intent of the robots.txt convention is that it's supposed to be an easy way to convey your desires to crawlers. In the earlier days of the web, dropping a text file into the root folder was very easy. As the web has developed, sites are much more programmatically-driven rather than file-driven, so the convention is a bit harder to deal with. But you can't really *stop* crawlers from requesting robots.txt since they have no way of knowing if they're supposed to hit other URLs on that hostname until they process it, so they're always going to try requesting it. You just need to deal with it.

### Is there some configuration I could add to my Web API to force a text response of my design for the robots.txt request?

Here's the steps I took to create a robots.txt for my API Gateway:

1. Create a new Resource, with name `robots.txt` and path `robots.txt`. Note that the console will try to have the path be `robots-txt` (with a hyphen instead) by default, so you need to be sure to change it.

   [image: Create Resource]

   [image: Set Resource Name]
2. Create a new Method for that resource, for GET.

   [image: Create Method]

   [image: New Method is for GET]
3. Choose Integration Type of Mock.

   [image: Integration type is Mock]
4. In the "Integration Response" section, expand the section for status 200, expand the section for "Body Mapping Templates", and click on `application/json`. Change the content type to `text/plain`, and put the desired robots.txt content¹ in the template box. Click Save.

   [image: Go to Integration Response section]

   [image: Expand status 200]

   [image: Expand Body Mapping Templates]

   [image: Edit application/json]

   [image: Change content type, include robots.txt content, and Save]
5. Go back and open up the "Method Response" section. Expand the section for status 200, click the pencil icon to edit the `application/json` response body type. Change it to `text/plain`, and click the checkmark to save.

   [image: Go to Method Response section]

   [image: Expand section for status 200]

   [image: Click pencil to edit]

   [image: Change to text/plain and Save]
6. Repeat steps 2 through 5, but for HEAD instead of GET. (I believe that there could be robots that check for existence with HEAD before getting the file with GET.) It looks like you need to put the same robots.txt content in the template box, even though the response won't actually get sent for a HEAD request, to have the correct Content-Length header sent.
7. Deploy to your test stage, and ensure that the robots.txt URL works properly, and responds with a `text/plain` Content-Type for both HEAD and GET.
8. Deploy to your production stage when ready.

---

¹ I expect that most API systems would want to use the [standard method to exclude all robots](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html):

> ```
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /
> ```

Comment: Hi, I tried your proposal but there is no application/json or pencil in the Method Response for me. And I can't add a response body because I have to define a model for it??

Comment: @StefanPeter: I've added step-by-step screenshots of what I've done. Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow Peter, thanks for the effort. But there is a difference to my gateway. In the Method Execution; there is NO http response. It's just empty.
I can add a response for 200, but than I can't add a body because it wants a model for that, which I don't have and don't know how it has to look like.
https://imagebin.ca/v/3VV2UDDTOZCA

Comment: @StefanPeter: I'm not sure what to tell you… I took those screenshots creating a brand new API. The 200 response was already there; I just changed it. Certainly possible I changed something in some settings somewhere that I don't remember, but if so, I, well, don't remember doing so. Maybe it's different between regions? I'm working in us-east-1 if that helps.

Comment: I "stole" an empty model from another API and was able to set everything as you said. Now I have to check the logs if it works. Thanks for the hints. :)

Comment: After years of avoiding this topic I had to return to this again. :) Now I know why this a approach here is not working for me. Because we're using a lambda function with this proxy path in the api gateway. Any request is send to the lambda function.
The solution for us would be to return the robots.txt content from the lambda function. But we have multiple stages in the api gateway and therefor multiple base path mappings thus we're not allowed to have an empty base path mapping to a stage so it could handle the requests. :(